# How to extract tr table row values using Selenium from a hidden chart? (Overflow:hidden)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the source I want to scrape data from https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/world-interest-rates

When you click on each bank's name, a chart would pops up and there are table rows and data values.

However, this charts are hidden. Because the attribute overflow:hidden.

How do I extract all the values that are in the chart?

I have already wrote a code that manages to iterate through and click each bank's name to display the chart.

But I have no idea how to extract the values from the charts. Please help. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/world-interest-rates')
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
time.sleep(10)

read_mores = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href="#"]')

for read in read_mores:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read)
    driver.execute_script("(arguments[0]).click();", read)
    time.sleep(1)

    list_of_rows = []
    table = soup.select("table")[0] 
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll(["th","td"]):
            list_of_cells.append(cell.text)
            list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

    for item in list_of_rows:
        print(' '.join(item))

    time.sleep(1)


driver.quit()
```

Comment: What are the chart values you want to extract ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question correctly, but if you need to extract the hidden table values of the chart you can try something like below.

After you click on the chart link try the below code to get the table values. (my code is in java)

```
List<WebElement> trs = driver().findElements((By.xpath("//div[contains(@aria-label,'tabular')]/table/tbody/tr")));
        for(WebElement tr : trs) {
            //  String name = we.getText();
            List<WebElement> tds = tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));               
            String date = tds.get(0).getAttribute("textContent");
            String rate = tds.get(1).getAttribute("textContent");
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(rate); 
        }
```

**OUTPUT**

Feb 15, 1990

16.5

Apr 4, 1990

15

Aug 2, 1990

14